# Is there a justified navbar for Bootstrap like jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, jquery-mobile-navbar

im searching for a mobile navbar with 3 navbaritems.

I found a navbar in the jQuery-Doc http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

In the Bootstrap-Doc I found this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

But I need a navbar, which is looking like the navbar from jQuery but using Bootstrap!

Does somebody know a way, how to do this with Bootstrap?

Thank you very much for answering!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956741/mobile-bootstrap-navbar-not-working

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/ -- add three items. You'll have to learn some css to style it the way you want

Comment: @Sahriar rahman supto - no this is not what I'm searching for, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Christina - how should I do this, I've no idea. Do you have an example?